# JSDoc: Enum and class not documented correctly

Tags: javascript, enums, ecmascript-6, jsdoc, documentation-generation

I have the following class

```
/** My special class */
export default class MyClass { 
    /**
     * An interesting value
     * @readonly
     * @enum {number}
     */ 
    static TEST = {
        /** Critical value */
        BAR: 1,
        /** Default value */
        FOO: 2
    }
}
```

Now, when I run `jsdoc`

```
$> /node_modules/.bin/jsdoc test.js
```

I see in the generated documentation

[image]

A Class named `exports` and **Bar** and **Foo** have became globals. The Enum TEST is a member of the class, but not related anymore with Bar and Foo. Any suggestions what I do wrong with jsdoc ?

([jsdoc enum](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-enum.html))